To print big integers using expressions why we need to declare initial variable as long too
so basically I had a code where I wanted to get the cube of the given integer
the input can be as big as 10^6 so when i used long long int and size_t and they did not work
until I changed the data type of input to long long on a whim.
Can someone please explain why this happened?
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    long long t;cin>>t;
    long long ans=t*t*t;
    cout<<ans;
    return 0;
}

also this happened even on while simply using cout instead of storing it in a variable first.

It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

I think this might be asking why t has to be declared as long long, why it's not sufficient for ans to be declared as long long.

If you write this long int t; ... long long ans = t*t*t; then the multiplication is done using long int because that is the type of t. It does not matter that ans is long long. Only the types of the operands taking part matter, not the final destination of the calculation.

Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? And What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?

You have posted code that works, but asked about different code, (unseen) that does not.  Post the code you are asking about and include verbatim (i e. copy &, paste) the exact diagnostic message you receive or the output if it is a runtime error

Why int t Causes an Overflow Error
Consider the following program, where t is declared as a 4 byte integer:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    long long ans= t*t*t;
    cout<<ans;
    return 0;
}

When I input 1,000,000 as you have stated I receive an incorrect value:
1000000
-1486618624

Since t is an 4 byte integer, The multiplication t*t*t will return a 4 byte integer, and then implicitly casted to an 8 byte integer when it is moved in ans
However since a 4 byte integer can only store a value up to 2,147,483,647 and (10^6)^3 > 2,147,483,647. This results in an overflow error in the multiplication, yielding this erroneous negative value which is then casted to an 8 byte integer, when it is moved into ans (where it remains this erroneous value).
Why long long t doesnt cause an Overflow Error
Changing the declaration of t so that it is a long long:
long long t;

long long is an 8-byte integer, hence that the multiplication t*t*t will return an 8 byte integer and then moved in ans.
An 8 byte integer can store values up to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 and (10^6)^3 < 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 so they wont be an overflow and it will correctly output '1,000,000,000,000,000,000`.
Explicit Casting to prevent overflow error
Alternatively, you could leave t as an int and explicitly cast the multiplication t*t*t to a long long as follows:
    int t; cin>>t;
    long long ans= (long long) t*t*t;

I believe this explicitly tells the compiler to store the result of the multiplication t*t*t as a 8 byte integer and not a 4 byte integer (which prevents the overflow)
